git cherry-pick and github pull request not syncing
In our case, we do not want to raise a PR in GitHub. Instead, we prefer to use cherry-pick to merge files from the cherry-pick-test branch to the main branch and keep the code up to date.
To achieve this, we performed the following steps. These steps can be followed to reproduce the issue:
    git clone repo-url
    git checkout -b cherry-pick-test
    echo "commit-1" > cherry_test.txt
    git add .\cherry_test.txt
    git commit -m "commit-1"
    git push origin cherry-pick-test
    git log --graph --oneline --all # I performed this command to get commit hash, you can use convenient command to gather same info 
    git checkout main
    git cherry-pick aab828a894dd13c05bc16ed799a7842c6a8c4d6b
    git push origin main

After performing the above commands, the main branch is up to date, meaning cherry_test.txt is merged/added to the main branch.
Occasionally, we need to raise a PR from cherry-pick-test to main. During this time, I expect that the changes from "commit-1" (commit hash aab828a894dd13c05bc16ed799a7842c6a8c4d6b) should not show up for merging again because they have already been pushed to main using cherry-pick.
My expectation is that when I raise a PR, it should not show previously cherry-picked/merged files in the PR. Can we achieve this, or is the system designed this way? I appreciate your help.
Screenshot of the PR raised in GitHub is attached below.


Why is there a backslash in git add .\cherry_test.txt?

You would need to push the changes from main up to your remote (Github) in order for the PR to not include them

@Phil backslash is due to windows host and i performed "git push origin main" missed to included in steps and added it

Git ("the system") is designed this way. Git cares about commits and commit history, not about changes between commits. You manually applied the changes of one commit to a different part of the history, so you also have to manually update Git's idea of what "is already merged". One way to achieve that is to rebase the feature branch onto the updated main branch. (One more thing: "merge" has a particular meaning in Git, and the way you use the word is not how Git uses it.)

As already said by @j6t in the comments, when merging branches, Git reasons in terms of commits not changes. In this scenario, Git looks for a commit from which the two merging branches diverged (their merge base). Once a commit has been selected, Git adds every change introduced by both branches on top of the merge base and then finalizes the merge, unless any conflicts are present. In this last scenario, Git leaves the burden of conflict resolution and merge finalization to the user.
Instead, when cherry-picking a commit, Git creates a whole new commit (with a different SHA1) that introduces the same changes of the cherry-picked revision.
Therefore, when you're merging cherry-pick-test into main, Git first selects the parent commit of cherry-pick-test's head as the merge base, and then adds on top of it the changes introduced by cherry-pick-test and main. However, since both branches are just one commit ahead from their merge base, and since both commits introduce the exact same change; when checking your PR on GitHub it will list both changes coming from the two different commits as a single one because they look the same.

My expectation is that when I raise a PR, it should not show previously cherry-picked/merged files in the PR. Can we achieve this, or is the system designed this way?

So, to answer your question:
You cannot achieve your PR to not showing a change coming from a commit on the other branch just because a change that happens to look the same is already present in the target branch. When merging branches, Git works with commits rather than raw content.
